# Do Lie derivatives commute with divergence: $\mathcal{L}_\xi \nabla_\mu V^\mu = \nabla_\mu \mathcal{L}_\xi V^{\mu}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

So my question is: given a vector field $V^\mu$ on some manifold with metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ is it necessarily true that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_\xi \nabla_\mu V^\mu = \nabla_\mu \mathcal{L}_\xi V^{\mu} \ ?
\end{equation} 
where $\nabla_\mu$ denote the covariant derivative satisfying the metric compatibility condition $\nabla_\lambda g_{\mu\nu} = 0$ and $\mathcal{L}_\xi$ is the Lie derivative. If so how do I show that?
If not, then is there any condition we could impose on $\xi$ such that this is true? i.e. Is it true if $\xi$ is a Killing vector or something like that?

Comment: I think it's true for Killing vector fields.

Comment: If $\xi$ is Killing, this is just the infinitesimal version of the fact that the divergence is invariant under isometries. In general, it is not true since essentially it would show that the divergence is invariant under diffeomorphisms.

Comment: So it should be true if $\xi$ is a Killing vector right? this is what I have been trying to proof but I'm not sure how. Basically what I've tried is $\nabla_\nu \mathcal{L}_\xi V^\nu = \nabla_\nu (\xi^\mu\nabla_\mu V^\nu - V^\mu\nabla_\mu \xi^\nu) = \xi^\mu\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu V^\nu - V^\mu \nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu \xi^\nu$. And then the left hand side is $\mathcal{L}_\xi \nabla_\nu V^\nu = \xi^\mu \partial_\mu \nabla_\nu V^\nu$. I'm not sure how to continue, I don't see how these two going to be equal, I don't even know where to apply the fact that $\xi$ is Killing. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think have got an answer but I'm not sure if it's right or not so I'm hoping that someone here could point out any potential mistake.

I think the conclusion is the identity is true if $\xi^\mu$ is a Killing vector. That means $\nabla_\nu \xi_\mu + \nabla_\mu \xi_\nu = 0$ and therefore $\nabla_\mu \xi^\mu = 0$. We have
\begin{align*}
\nabla_\mu \mathcal{L}_\xi V^\mu &= \nabla_\mu(\xi^\nu\nabla_\nu V^\mu - V^\nu \nabla_\nu \xi^\mu) \\
&= \xi^\nu \nabla_{\mu}\nabla_\nu V^\mu - V^\nu \nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu \xi^\mu \\
&= \xi^\nu\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu V^\mu + \xi^\nu[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu]V^\mu - V^\nu\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu \xi^\mu - V^\nu[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu]\xi^\mu \\
&= \xi^\nu\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu V^\mu + \xi^\nu[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu]V^\mu - V^\nu[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu]\xi^\mu
\end{align*}
Now, using the identity
\begin{equation}
[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu]v^\rho = R^\rho_{\ \sigma\mu\nu}v^\sigma
\end{equation}
where $R^\rho_{\ \sigma\mu\nu}$ is the Riemann curvature tensor. From this, we find that
\begin{equation}
\xi^\nu[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu]V^\mu = R^\mu_{\ \sigma\mu\nu}\xi^\nu V^\sigma = R_{\sigma\nu}\xi^\nu V^\sigma
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
V^\nu[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu]\xi^\mu = R^{\mu}_{\ \sigma\mu\nu}\xi^\sigma V^\nu = R_{\sigma\nu}\xi^\sigma V^\nu = R_{\nu\sigma}\xi^\sigma V^\nu = \xi^\nu[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu]V^\mu
\end{equation}
where $R_{\sigma\nu} = R^\mu_{\ \sigma\mu\nu}$ is the Ricci tensor satisfying a well-known symmetry property $R_{\mu\nu} = R_{\nu\mu}$. Therefore, the last two terms in the expression for $\nabla_\mu \mathcal{L}_\xi V^\mu$ will cancel. We are left with
\begin{equation}
\nabla_\mu \mathcal{L}_\xi V^\mu = \xi^\nu\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu V^\mu = \xi^\nu\partial_\nu\nabla_\mu V^\mu = \mathcal{L}_\xi\nabla_\mu V^\mu
\end{equation} 
as required.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get $[L_\xi,\text{div}]X=0$ using coordinate invariant notation when $\xi$ is a Killing vector field.

Let $\epsilon$ be the volume form on the manifold. Then $L_X\epsilon = (\nabla\cdot X) \epsilon$. Then:

$$\nabla \cdot (L_\xi X) \epsilon = L_{L_\xi X} \epsilon = (L_\xi L_X - L_X L_\xi) \epsilon
\\
= L_\xi (\nabla \cdot X \epsilon) - L_X(\nabla \cdot \xi \epsilon)
\\
=L_\xi(\nabla \cdot X) \epsilon + \nabla \cdot X \nabla \cdot \xi \epsilon - L_X(\nabla \cdot \xi) \epsilon - \nabla \cdot \xi \nabla \cdot X \epsilon
$$

Since $\xi$ is Killing, its divergence vanishes everywhere, meaning everything but the first term on the last line vanishes. The volume form is nonzero everywhere, so $\nabla \cdot (L_\xi X)=L_\xi(\nabla \cdot X)$.